# Fatal error: Call to a member function get_price_html() on a non-object

Tags: php, search, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display the price of each product in the search it works for most products but when I search for a piticular product I keep getting this error

Fatal error: Call to a member function getpricehtml() on a non-object in /home/public_html/wp-content/theme/search.php on line 76

this is the only search I get the error on "CUP0501-001 2822505 Jacobsen Reel Motor WMSM4".

Here is the line on the search page that is giving me trouble

getpricehtml(); ?>

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that search returns no results and instead returns a non-object such as `null` or `false`? Perhaps do a var_dump on the result before using `get_price_html` to see what the result is.

Comment: How would I code that into the page would it just be <?php var_dump(); ?>

Comment: It's returning an invalid value, so it's simply rejecting it. I'd go with Mr.Kuhn, and do some testing to see what the result is and if it's valid. If you can post some of the code, we could help you out a bit easier.

Comment: <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
 <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
   <div class="entry">
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
      <h3>
       <?php the_title(); ?>
      </h3>
      <p itemprop="price" class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
      <p class="button">
       <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        Read more...
       </a>

Comment: Probably need to ensure $product exists before you call the get_price_html() method on it; try adding `global $product` at the start of your loop

Comment: Please edit your question with the new code. It is impossible to read code blocks in the comments. Ultimately, if you are calling `$product->getpricehtml()` (that isn't a default WC product class method) then `$product` must be an object or you will see the fatal error.

Comment: How would I add the global $product to my php file would I add it like this <?php global $product ?>

Comment: I added this code snippet in <p itemprop="price" class="price">
 <?php $product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() ); ?>
  <?php $price = $product->price; ?>
   <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
 Now it displays products that are not on the site.

Answer (score 4):

In this file `$product` is not defined, so define it.

This code might solve your problem.

```
global $woocommerce;
$product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID()); 
echo $product->get_price_html(); //Shows the price
```