# how to add function to div

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add function which will show the price of a product just below the sale badge, but i am having trouble with the code.. it works just fine in frontend, but wordpress find it wrong and shows error in backend (when I open the plugin settings).

What is the right way to add this?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_price_html() on null in /wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-badge-management-premium/templates/badge_content_premium.php:36 Stack trace: #0 
/wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-badge-management-premium/functions.yith-wcbm.php(205): include() #1 
/wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-badge-management-premium/functions.yith-wcbm-premium.php(807): yith_wcbm_get_template('badge_content_p...', Array) #2 
/wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-badge-management-premium/class.yith-wcbm-admin-premium.php(109): yith_wcbm_get_badge_premium(364, 'preview') #3 
/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): YITH_WCBM_Admin_Premium->badge_custom_columns('yith_wcbm_previ...' in 
/wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-badge-management-premium/templates/badge_content_premium.php on line 36
```

**Here is the code i am adding on line 36**

```
<div class='<?php echo $badge_classes ?> yith-wcbm-badge-custom' <?php echo $position_data_html ?>>

            <div class='yith-wcbm-badge__wrap'>
                <div class="yith-wcbm-badge-text"><b><?php echo $text ?>
LINE 36-      <div class="roundedborder"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></b></div></div>
            </div><!--yith-wcbm-badge__wrap-->
        </div><!--yith-wcbm-badge-->
```

I've tried to define $product and obviously i do something wrong also tried `global $woocommerce; $product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID());` none of them solves the problem

Comment: [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486911/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-get-price-html-on-a-non-object#40403586)

Answer (score 0):

This Error is generated because your $product is null, try to get the product object than get the price

Comment: i've tried to place global $product on the top of the rules and still receiving error :/

Comment: I've tried to define `$product` and obviously i do something wrong also tried `global $woocommerce;
    $product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID()); ` none of them solves the problem

Answer (score -1):

It seems like object $product not exists.
Here is the same problem, may be helps you:

[Fatal error: Call to a member function get_price_html() on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486911/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-get-price-html-on-a-non-object)

```
<?php
    global $woocommerce;
    $product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID()); 
    echo $product->get_price_html(); //Shows the price
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggest, i've tried it and the error now changes to

Comment: Uncaught Exception: Invalid product. in 
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php:163 Stack trace: #0 
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-data-store.php(159): WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT->read(Object(WC_Product)) #1

Comment: /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php(135): WC_Data_Store->read(Object(WC_Product)) #2 
/wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-badge-management-premium/templates/badge_content_premium.php(29): WC_Product->__construct(364) #3 
/wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-badge-management-premium/functions.yith-wcbm.php(205): include('/homepages/13/d...') #4 /homepages/13/d767788347/htdocs/clickand in /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php on line 163

Comment: you have a problem creating the product object, so try to check if the function get_the_ID() retrieve the correct product ID, if you got nothing be sure you send a product id to this page,

Comment: 0

SOLVED!!

`global $woocommerce;
$product = new WC_Product($product_id);
echo $product->get_price_html();`
For me it takes 4 days.... hope next person reading enjoy it :)