# Call to a member function get_price_html() on null - Wordpress/WooCommerce/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I've created a plugin on Wordpress with Gutenberg, which deletes a lot of blocks on the "single-product" page. I wanted to create a nice page for each products.

To do this, in my plugin, I created a function which removes all the layout of WooCommerce.

After that, I created a function which creates a "block" in Gutenberg which displays the price whereIi want, as well as the "add to cart".

To display the price, here is my code :

```
function lsc_product_price() {
    ob_start();
    woocommerce_template_single_price();
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $content;
}
```

The code is almost the same for the "add to cart".

When I use my "price" block with Gutenberg, some times, my cart is down and I can't even access to the cart page.

There is the error of Wordpress :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_price_html() on null in /home/.../public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/price.php:25

At this line, we have :

```
<p class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_price_class', 'price' ) ); ?>"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
```

I know that there may be a conflict between plugins, and I know that my plugin conflicts suddenly.

I understand the error, but I don't know how to resolve it. I tried to search some info on Google or StackOverFlow, but I couldn’t find anything that would help me.

Comment: So it seems that `product` does not have a function called get_price_html

Comment: Try this ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486911/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-get-price-html-on-a-non-object

Comment: @MartinMirchev yes, i tried before publishing this post, but nothing :/ Thanks !

Comment: @mplungjan yes that's what i though, but where can i put this .....

Comment: Make sure your plugin is not loading before woocommerce ?

Comment: @MartinMirchev thanks for your answer, but how can i know that ? :/

Comment: Check this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193907/how-to-check-if-a-plugin-woocommerce-is-active and also this - https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/create-a-plugin/

Comment: @MartinMirchev thanks i'll check that